# Sampling according to distribution from a large vetor in R

Tags: r, bigdata

I have a large vector of 11 billion values. The distribution of the data is not know and therefore I would like to sample 500k data points based on the existing probabilities/distribution. In R there is a limitation of values that can be loaded in a vector - 2^31 -1 which is why I plan to do the sampling manually.

Some information about the data: The data is just integers. And many of them are repeated multiple times.

`large.vec <- (1,2,3,4,1,1,8,7,4,1,...,216280)`

To create the probabilities of 500k samples across the distribution I will first create the probability sequence.

`prob.vec <- seq(0,1,,500000)`

Next, convert these probabilities to position in the original sequence.

`position.vec <- prob.vec*11034432564`

The reason I created the position vector is so that I can pic data point at the specific position after I order the population data.

Now I count the occurrences of each integer value in the population. Create a data frame with the integer values and their counts. I also create the interval for each of these values

`integer.values        counts          lw.interval         up.interval 
    0               300,000,034            0               300,000,034
    1               169,345,364         300,000,034        469,345,398
    2               450,555,321         469,345,399        919,900,719
...`

Now using the position vector, I identify which position value falls in which interval and based on that get the value of that interval.

This way I believe I have a sample of the population. I got a large chunk of the idea from this reference,
[Calculate quantiles for large data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985166/calculate-quantiles-for-large-data).

*I wanted to know if there is a better approach? Or if this approach could reasonably, albeit crudely give me a good sample of the population?*

This process does take a reasonable amount of time, as the position vector as to go through all possible intervals in the data frame. For that I have made it parallel using RHIPE.

I understand that I will be able to do this only because the data can be ordered.

I am not trying to randomly sample here, I am trying to "sample" the data keeping the underlying distribution intact. Mainly reduce 11 billion to 500k.

Comment: `help("LongVectors")` could be relevant here. Also, why can't you simply `sample` from the data?

Comment: @Roland I am not able to sample from the data mainly because I cannot get the data into a vector to pass it to sample. And I have found that picking values by using probabilities has given me a better sample than just using sample. Do you suggest I get the data in a vector (using long vector) and then sample by passing probabilities to the sample function?

Comment: I don't understand why you feel the need to pass probabilities. Normally you'd just take a random sample. I don't know if `sample` supports long vectors already and can't test with the memory on my system. If you can't do it in R, use something better suited for sampling from such big datasets.